# Accessing property in my struts action from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts

I am still trying to get my head around how client server comms work with JSP/js and Struts.
I have a Struts property in my action that I can display on my page using 
As I understand it this works by looking in my Action for a method called getMyMessage().  So this works ok for me.
I now want to be able to access this value from inside my Javascript so I can dynamically populate a test area when the page loads.
I use

```
$(document).ready(function( data )
{
$('#contextsTextArea').html(data.myMessage);
});
```

but this does not work.  I know I could assign a var in my JSP that stores the struts property and reference this var in my JS but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: can you log `data` for us ? What `contextsTextArea` is ?

Comment: contextsTextArea is the id of my jsp textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP runs on the server, JavaScript runs in your browser.

You cannot use a JSP variable like 'myMessage' as a variable in your JavaScript. You can, however, turn it into text on the server so it works as JS when it gets to your browser. 
So, try something like this:

```
$('#contextsTextArea').val('<s:property value="myMessage"/>')
```

When this JSP is processed on the server the JS code will be left as text while the  tag will be turned into the text in your myMessage variable.

Note that you really need to JS escape myMessage otherwise, for example, if the message contains a single quote then the JS will break.

Have a look at your page source to understand what's going on here.

Comment: cheers,  that clears it up.  I didn't realise you could actually embed JSP tags within your JS code,  I thought it could only work the other way round,  ie JS embedded within your JSP tags.

Comment: You can only do that if your JS code is in your JSP page of course- JSP code in a .js file won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `textarea` you have to use `.val()` instead. Like the following.
`$('#contextsTextArea').val(data.myMessage);`

Comment: no, this doesnt work.  <s:property  value="myMessage"/>  displays my message fine so there is nothing wrong on the server side.

Comment: $('#contextsTextArea').val("a string");  displays ok so the problem is not with the construct on my js side.  Just seems that data.myMessage just does not generate a call into my action class for the myMessage attribute.